# How to get the maximum _id value in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

We use a custom `_id` field which is a `long` value. I would like to get the max _id value. The search I am making is -

```
{
  "stored_fields": [
    "_id"
  ],
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": {
    "_id": "desc"
  },
  "size": 1
}
```

But I get error back from ES 5.1 as-

```
"reason": {
              "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
              "reason": "Fielddata access on the _uid field is disallowed"
}
```

So, how do I go about getting the max value of `_id`. I don't really want to store copy of `_id` inside the doc just to get the max value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should sort by the `_uid` field not by the `_id` field. The `_id` field is not accessible for sorting (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-id-field.html).

```
{
  "stored_fields": [
    "_id"
  ],
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": {
    "_uid": "desc"
  },
  "size": 1
}
```